# MS Access query , getting Join Not Supported

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

So I am trying to create a code that pulls information from an access database, however I am getting "Join Not Supported"

```
sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT ordID, ordTrackNum, ordShipCarrier, ordStatusDate FROM 
        orders INNER JOIN shipoptions ON ordID = soOrderID WHERE (ordStatus=6);"
```

I read somewhere you have to wrap it in brackets or parenthesis, but I have no idea where, could someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: So this is an access problem, not mysql ?

Comment: Yes, it is all using an access database

Answer (score 3):

Your JOIN syntax is wrong - you need to define which table those columns in the JOIN condition come from - either by using the full table name, or a table alias (not sure if MS Access supports this - I work with SQL Server most of the time).

So try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ordID, ordTrackNum, ordShipCarrier, ordStatusDate 
FROM 
    orders     
INNER JOIN 
    shipoptions ON orders.ordID = shopoptions.soOrderID 
WHERE 
    ordStatus = 6
```

No brackets or anything needed ....

Or if MS Access supports table aliases (or when used in SQL Server) - use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ordID, ordTrackNum, ordShipCarrier, ordStatusDate 
FROM 
    orders o
INNER JOIN 
    shipoptions so ON o.ordID = so.soOrderID 
WHERE 
    ordStatus = 6
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried both and still getting the JOIN NOT SUPPORTED, In the future we will be using SQL and hopefully this will make some things easier, but for now we are stuck with access :-/

Comment: What are the datatypes of ordID and soOrderID?

Comment: I was able to take care of it by removing the join statement completely, it was redundant